Why aren't there in vacuum any charges nor currents?
In this video (MIT $8.02$ course titled "Electricity and Magnetism", video number $214$, taught by Pr. Krishna Rajagopal), professor considers Maxwell's equations in the special case of the vacuum. He zeroes the terms that are related to charge (e.g. charge density) and to current (current density).
While I understand that in vacuum there's no current (since there's no atom to carry the charge). I don't quite get why there would be no charges as well.
Is that for the same reason as for the current, that is that there's no atom that could carry a charge?
Is it that simple?
It might be more complicated but I'd like to know if this explanation is good as a first approach?

A perfect vacuum, by definition, would contain no matter. Not just atoms, but basically any kind of matter, hence no charge. (Things are quite more complicated than that when it comes to QM though)

Not that long ago many people had a device in their house that sent an electron beam through vacuum. But that vacuum had electrons in it…

Charge density actually means that there is some density of charged particles. Vacuum = no particles = no charge density (and no current density). As simple as that.

When dealing with field equations, "in vacuum" means "in the absence of charges and currents" by definition. But yes, vacuum simply means empty space, so no charged particles can be in the considered spacetime region. They can still be outside the region, and influence it. This is why you get wave equations for the vacuum, even though there is nothing causing the wave.
